# SQL-SNOWFLAKE Take out BIG Data

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a huge file call it TABLE1 that I try to export such as this because it is like 29million row but I always get error and can never find this file when try to export. I am using WINDOWS  DESKTOP Machine.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY STAGE my_temp_stage;

COPY INTO @my_temp_stage/output_filex
FROM (select * FROM TABLE1)
FILE_FORMAT = ( 
 TYPE='CSV' 
 COMPRESSION=GZIP 
 FIELD_DELIMITER=',' 
 ESCAPE=NONE 
 ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD=NONE 
 date_format='AUTO' 
 time_format='AUTO' 
 timestamp_format='AUTO'
 binary_format='UTF-8' 
 field_optionally_enclosed_by='"' 
 null_if='' 
 EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = FALSE 
)  
overwrite=TRUE 
single=FALSE 
max_file_size=5368709120 
header=TRUE;

ls @my_temp_stage;

GET @my_temp_stage C:/USERS/DISTRICT/DOCUMENTS/BIGTABLE1.CSV ;
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What do you see when you `ls` the stage?

Comment: @ SQL COMPILATION ERROR: THE COMMAND IS NOT SUPPORTED FROM THE UI: GET

Comment: @GregPavlik I am afraid I do not know how to _ls_ the stage?

Comment: @bvowe You cannot use GET/PUT from Snowflake UI, you will need to use a client connector for that, like SnowSQL or Python/JDBC/ODBC etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, GEY/PUT can not be executed from the Worksheets page in the Snowflake web Snowflake UI/Snowsight etc. Its mentioned in the documentation.

Please refer the documentation for more details.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/put.html#usage-notes

You can use any other Snowflake connector such as Snowsql, JDBC etc for PUT.
You can also use streaming etc.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-using.html#upload-data-files-directly-from-a-stream-to-an-internal-stage

Regards,
Sujan